# Error fetching data from table in Presto HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

We are using Prestodb(0.69) and client on a single node server. 
Where in we are using hive catalog, with tables in ORC format, consisting of 350,000,000 rows.

While running the query "select column1 from ORC_Table1 where column2=123456789", we are getting HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR. 
The datatype of column2 is "int" 
Below is the error stack :-

```
    "failures" : [ { 
      "type" : "com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException", 
      "message" : "Read past end of RLE integer from compressed stream Stream for column 2 kind DATA position: 477741 length: 477741 range: 0 offset: 478409 limit: 478409 range 0 = 0 to 477741 uncompressed: 212681 to 212681", 
      "cause" : { 
        "type" : "java.io.EOFException", 
        "message" : "Read past end of RLE integer from compressed stream Stream for column 2 kind DATA position: 477741 length: 477741 range: 0 offset: 478409 limit: 478409 range 0 = 0 to 477741 uncompressed: 212681 to 212681", 
        "suppressed" : [ ], 
        "stack" : [ "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RunLengthIntegerReaderV2.readValues(RunLengthIntegerReaderV2.java:46)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RunLengthIntegerReaderV2.next(RunLengthIntegerReaderV2.java:287)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl$LongTreeReader.next(RecordReaderImpl.java:473)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl$StructTreeReader.next(RecordReaderImpl.java:1157)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.next(RecordReaderImpl.java:2196)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:106)", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$OrcRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:57)", "com.facebook.presto.hive.GenericHiveRecordCursor.advanceNextPosition(GenericHiveRecordCursor.java:241)", "ScanFilterAndProjectOperator_11.filterAndProjectRowOriented(Unknown Source)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.AbstractScanFilterAndProjectOperator.getOutput(AbstractScanFilterAndProjectOperator.java:177)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:329)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:271)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:674)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:443)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:577)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ] 
      }, 
      "suppressed" : [ ], 
      "stack" : [ "com.facebook.presto.hive.GenericHiveRecordCursor.advanceNextPosition(GenericHiveRecordCursor.java:257)", "ScanFilterAndProjectOperator_11.filterAndProjectRowOriented(Unknown Source)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.AbstractScanFilterAndProjectOperator.getOutput(AbstractScanFilterAndProjectOperator.java:177)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:329)", "com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:271)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:674)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(TaskExecutor.java:443)", "com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor$Runner.run(TaskExecutor.java:577)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ], 
      "errorCode" : { 
        "code" : 16777217, 
        "name" : "HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR" 
      }
```

---

The query runs fine on table consisting of few rows. 
Can anyone help me sort this out.

Below is the config.properties:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://172.168.1.99:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can Hive read this table?  If it can, this is likely a bug that has been fixed in a newer version of the Hive libraries than Presto is using, and you will need to wait until Presto upgrades to the newest Hive release.  If Hive can not read the table, the file is either corrupt or there is still a bug in the ORC reader.

Comment: Thanks @Dain
Will try with hive-0.13